# Will a VS2008 setup project update Net 3.5 SP1?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, setup-project, .net-3.5

I just started using the WPF WebBrowser that is included in Net 3.5 SP1.  I built my setup project (which I have been using prior to moving to 3.5 SP1) and installed it on a test machine but the WebBrowser was not available.

What must I do to be sure that the setup.exe/msi combination checks for and installs SP1?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open the properties of the Setup Project, then click on the Prerequesites button.  Then check the prerequisites to install.

[image: License]

Then you can define how the user gets the pre-reqs.

Here is a link to framework version information and an excerpt from Scott Hanselman's blog:

> Online/Download Experience
>   The best way to get a user with reasonable Internet connectivity up on the 3.5 SP1 .NET Framework is with the 2.7 Meg "bootstrapper."  This will detect what they need and only download what they need. The worst-case scenario for a x86 machine is around 60 megs, as seen in the table above.
>
> What's the "Client Profile?"
>   The Client Profile is an even smaller install option for .NET 3.5 SP1 on XP. It's small 277k bootstrapper. When it's run on a Windows XP SP2 machines with no .NET Framework installed, it will download a 28 meg payload and give you a client-specific subset of .NET 3.5.  If the Client Profile bootstrapper is run on a machine with any version of .NET on it, it'll act the same as the 3.5 SP1 web installer and detect what it needs to download, then go get it.  There's more details in the Client Profile Deployment Guide.

http://www.hanselman.com/blog/CommentView.aspx?guid=af453d70-64b3-417e-9492-d115f929195d

Comment: also should mention the launch condition and the fact that the check is for 3.5, not SP1 so 3.5 owners will not be auto forced to upgrade to SP1

Comment: when I say the check, I refer to the launch condition which is triggered when you run the MSI [directly, not via the bootstrapper].

Answer (score 0):

On my way to answering my own question.  Double-clicking on the Microsoft .net Framework in the Detected dependencies one can choose the version.

Now the question is which is appropriate, **3.5.30729** or **3.5 SP1 Client**?

**EDIT:** 3.5.30729 works.  Any ideas of the difference between the two?

**EDIT:** Double-clicking on the .net Framework above shows .NET Framework as a Launch condition.  This is where I changed the version.  (I'd add a screenshot, but I don't have one at a URL, only on my desktop.

Comment: Client more than likely means Client Profile, i.e. the subset of the framework that doesnt have e.g. ASP.NET

Comment: NB If 3.5 is installed, doesnt warn you need 3.5, see http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/netfxsetup/thread/698a0f78-1808-45f1-a615-f3acec50a84d/ and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/245913/delivery-of-net-3-5-sp1

Answer (score 0):

In the setup project, add some launch conditions. This page shows you how exactly:
http://jelle.druyts.net/2005/04/09/CheckingForNET11ServicePack1InAnMSI.aspx

Comment: That checks for a SP1, but what about when 4.0 is installed and you're happy with that instead of 3.5SP1 ? (BTW amended reg paths at http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/netfxsetup/thread/698a0f78-1808-45f1-a615-f3acec50a84d/)