# Delivery of .Net 3.5 SP1

Tags: .net, .net-3.5, installation

If I were to include .Net Framework setup file along with my apps (installation process is done by our own technician), to be install on a clean Windows (XP SP2/SP3 or Vista SP1) without prior installation of any framework, which of the .Net Framework setup do I need to install in sequence, to get to 3.5 SP1?
Currently I have the setup file for:

1. .Net 2.0
2. .Net 2.0 SP1
3. .Net 3.0
4. .Net 3.5
5. .Net 3.5 SP1

All redistributable version.

EDIT : I need the full installation, client profile won't work as our client's machine might not have internet access. Basically I need a install-and-forget-it procedure, so when we decided to use anything new within 3.5 SP1 later, we can rest assure that we can just simple apply update our apps without having to install another pre-requisite

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The .Net Framework 3.5 SP1 redistributable (the one that's around 230MB) contains everything (2.0 + SP1 + SP2, 3.0 + SP1 + SP2, 3.5 + SP1) in all supported architectures (x86, x64, ia64). **This is the only download you need.**

[Download from here](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=AB99342F-5D1A-413D-8319-81DA479AB0D7&displaylang=en) (click on [.NET Framework 3.5 Service Pack 1 (Full Package)](http://download.microsoft.com/download/2/0/e/20e90413-712f-438c-988e-fdaa79a8ac3d/dotnetfx35.exe)):

And then, you might want to install [these updates](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=136730):

> IMPORTANT: After installing the .NET Framework 3.5 SP1 package (either the bootstrapper or the full package) you should immediately install the update [KB959209](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=136730) to address a set of known application compatibility issues.

There are 3 updates (for 2.0, 3.0, and 3.5) for 2 OS "groups" (XP/2003 or Vista/2008) for 3 architectures (x86, x64, or ia64), for a total of... 16 downloads! (I know, 3 * 2 * 3 = 18, but Server 2003 ia64 only supports up to 2.0). You need to install the 3 updates in order. Or you could run Windows Update after installing 3.5 SP1 and let it figure it out.

---

EDIT: To be clear, .Net 3.5 requires that 2.0 and 3.0 be installed and updated to SP1 level. .Net 3.5 SP1 requires that 2.0/3.0 be updated to SP2 level. But the 3.5(SP1) installers will do this automatically. That is, by installing 3.5 SP1, you don't need to worry about installing and updating 2.0 and 3.0 to SP1 or SP2. **Just install 3.5 SP1 and you're done!** (and the extra updates, 3.5 SP1.1?)

About the Client Profile, it can only be installed on x86 client machines that don't have ANY version of .Net installed, so it won't install on Vista (it already comes with .Net 3.0), any Windows Server version, nor any x64/ia64 OS. You can only install it on a Windows XP SP2+ (x86) that doesn't have any version of .Net installed, otherwise a full installation is done. The offline Client Profile installer is 255MB because it will try to do a client install first, if it can't it will fallback to a full install. Personally, I would just do a full install anyway.

Comment: This is what I was waiting for. Thanks

Answer (score 9):

NET 3.5 SP1 introduces a new setup package option for developers building .NET client applications called the "[.NET Framework Client Profile](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/05/12/visual-studio-2008-and-net-framework-3-5-service-pack-1-beta.aspx)".This provides a new setup installer that enables a smaller, faster, and simpler installation experience for .NET client applications on machines that do not already have the .NET Framework installed.

The .NET Framework Client Profile setup contains just those assemblies and files in the .NET Framework that are typically used for client application scenarios.  For example: it includes Windows Forms, WPF, and WCF.  It does not include ASP.NET and those libraries and components used primarily for server scenarios.  We expect this setup package to be about **26MB** in size, and it can be downloaded and installed much quicker than the full .NET Framework setup package.